# Can't access files from src/main/resources via a test-case

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a `file.dat` in `src/main/resources`.

When I try to test a class which loads this file via a jar file, the test fails because its not able to find the file in the path (`I/O Exception`). The path which I get via test is:

`/home/usr/workspace/project/target/test-classes/file.dat`

but the file is not exist in `target/test-classes` any idea?

Comment: Why would it be in `target/test-cases`?

Comment: test classPath is `target/test-classes` so compiled test cases goes there.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Files from `src/main/resources` will be available on the classpath during runtime of the main program, while files both from `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` will be available on the classpath during test runs.

One way to retrieve files residing on the classpath is:

```
Object content = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("file.dat").getContent();
```

.. where the type of `content` depends on the file contents. You can also get the file as an InputStream:

```
InputStream contentStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.dat");
```

Comment: Oh thanks @adam-arold and sorry for such a silly mistake

Answer (score 5):

If the file is in

> src/main/resources/file.dat

You can get the URL to the file :

> getClass().getResource("/file.dat");

Comment: Actually returns an URL and not an absolute path. But you can derive the path from it.