# getResourceAsStream returns null with correct path

Tags: java

my piece of code:

```
private InputStream assetFromJAR(String fileName) {
    return getClass().getResourceAsStream("/view/assets/ims/" + fileName + ".png");
}
```

returns always null...

My structure is:

```
src
  main
   java  <- source root
     view
       assets
         ims
```

it does not make sence why is this happening, path is correct so why does it always return null?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Because the `java` folder is for Java source files (`*.java`), which will be compiled to `*.class` files. Other types of files (e.g. `*.png`) should be placed in the `resources` folder, because they don't need to be transformed (compiled).

Comment: @Andreas if u put inside resource folder, it still returns null edited question

Comment: Also, if you use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`, it will locate the file relative to the directory the class file is in. Use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` when file is relative to a classpath root like in your example. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875635/cant-access-files-from-src-main-resources-via-a-test-case/18876090#18876090

Comment: @jejjejd *"edited question"* I see no edit of the question.

Comment: @JonasBerlin Since the parameter value starts with `/`, the path is absolute, not relative to the class. So says the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).

Comment: @jejjejd *"if u put inside resource folder"* That should be `resources`, plural. Next to the `java` folder, i.e. `src/main/resources/view/assets/ims`

Answer (score 0):

Maven java projects are structured in way to separate the *.java files and resource files(like *.properties, *.jpg, *.png, etc..)

- For *.java files: src/main/java folder
- For resources: src/main/resources

So place your resources files directly under "src/main/resources" or sub folder of resources directory(like "src/main/resources/view/assets/ims/" for your project).

Then you can easily access the resource files.

```
private InputStream assetFromJAR(String fileName) {
     return getClass().getResourceAsStream("/view/assets/ims/" + fileName + ".png");
}
```

Comment: The leading `/` is **required**, otherwise the path is relative to the package of the class.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to start with some things that are obvious, because you haven't indicated what you've tried.  I apologize if you've done, or are aware of this:

Paths that begin with "/" are found somewhere in the class path.  Paths without the beginning "/", start from where the code is called. Your class path roots may not be what you think they are, or the .png file is not being moved from your source directory to your target directory.

Have you verified the file is in the target directory ( assuming your using maven for building), or wherever your .class files end up?

Have you verified what you're class path roots are?

Comment: What are you trying to say in your talk about the `/`? The question makes it clear that the `view/assets/ims` path is from the root of classpath, not relative to the package of the class, which we don't even know what is, so the leading `/` is **required**.